# Login into EC2 Instance as root

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, root

I am using putty to login to my ec2 instance. When i typed root it asked me to login as ec2-user.

> Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key" Please login as
>   the ec2-user user rather than root user.

when  i did login as ec2-user and tried to run commands like

> yum install httpd

it says

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security, update-motd You
>   need to be root to perform this command.

I am running the instance for the first time. I tried searching through the amazon aws help section and google. Not able to find the solution.

Comment: Switch to root with su or execute the command as sudo if thats installed.

Comment: sudo yum install httpd, or change as root by sudo su -

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To switch to a root shell, run the command:

```
su
```

If you want to execute a command as root without switching to a root shell, you can use:

```
sudo yum install httpd
```

Answer (score 4):

- Write the below command before writing any command

`sudo su`

After that you will be the root user. Enjoy:)

Comment: sudo su? Isn't that like putting a hat on a hat?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me when I add `sudo` in front of `yum install` command:

```
sudo yum install docker
```

Answer (score 1):

if anyone want to switch back to root user merely type command "exit" in your user terminal.